# Getting previous and next element of a value in a Scala enumeration

Tags: scala, enumeration

I would like to add two new operations to a Scala [Enumeration](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Enumeration) to get the previous and the next value given a certain value if it exists. For example, I would like to write something like:

```scala
object Nums extends MyNewEnumerationType {
  type Nums = Value
  val One,Two,Three = Value
}

Nums.nextOf(One) // Some(Two)
Nums.prevOf(One) // None
```

My idea was to create a new class and add the methods in this way:

```scala
class PrevNextEnum extends Enumeration {

  val prevOf = values.zip(None +: values.map{_.some}.toSeq).toMap
  val nextOf = {
    if (values.isEmpty) Map.empty
    else values.zip(values.tail.map{_.some}.toSeq :+ None).toMap
  }

}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work because when `prevOf` and `nextOf` are initialized, `values` is empty.

First question: why `values` is empty and when it is filled with the values?

Second question: how can I implement `prevOf` and `nextOf`?

Third question: is it possible to add the methods `prevOf` and `nextOf` to the value type instead of the enumeration? Writing `One.next` feels more natural than writing `Num.nextOf(One)`

Answer (score 1):

try the following codes:

```
class PrevNextEnum extends Enumeration {

 lazy val prevOf = {
   val list = values.toList
   val map = list.tail.zip(list.map(Some(_))).toMap + (list.head -> None)
   map
 }
 lazy val nextOf = {
  val list = values.toList
  val map = (list.zip(list.tail.map(Some(_)) :+ None).toMap)
  map
 }
}

object Nums extends PrevNextEnum {
 type Nums = Value
 val One, Two, Three = Value
}

object App extends App {
  println(Nums.prevOf(Nums.Two))
  println(Nums.nextOf(Nums.One))
  println(Nums.nextOf(Nums.Three))
  println(Nums.prevOf(Nums.One))
}
```

Comment: It works but it seems very fragile: if you use `lazy` you are assuming that `prevOf` and `nextOf` will be called after `values` is initialized. I want to initalize them after `values` somehow. Is it possible?
Another thing: can you explain why are you converting `values` to `List`?
Thank you.

Comment: actually, I am not a expert on scala too, I just tried some codes, and this way works. and if you go into values API, you will see values is actually a method, instead of some "values" initialized after the enumeration creation. So, if you want to call "values" in the parent before even child declare some value, one way is to make it lazy, so, it will only be initialized during the first call, otherwise, you will get an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer of user1484819 :

```
class PrevNextEnum extends Enumeration {

  lazy val prevOf = {
    val list = values.toList
    val map = list.tail.zip(list).toMap
    v:Value => map.get(v)
  }
  lazy val nextOf = {
    val list = values.toList
    val map = list.zip(list.tail).toMap
    v:Value => map.get(v)
  }
}

object Nums extends PrevNextEnum {
  type Nums = Value
  val One, Two, Three = Value
}
```

This has basically the same structure, but uses the fact that `Map` can return `Options` itself when using `get` instead of `apply`.